# Error loading repositories

Tags: azure-container-registry

In the Azure portal, when I go to my Container Registry and click on Repositories (under Services), my repositories don't load and I get the error message `Error loading repositories`.

The console of Chrome contains the following error messages:

`GET https://REMOVED.azurecr.io/v2/_catalog 401 (Unauthorized) - REMOVED.azurecr.io/v2/_catalog:1`

`[Microsoft_Azure_ContainerRegistries]  1:20:06 PM - 
 efe5474C39B089216811DEA68B8392644A0C676A067.js:24` (With body:)

```
MsPortalFx.Base.Diagnostics.ErrorReporter 1 MsPortalFx.Base.Diagnostics.ErrorReporter: _errorData: undefined  
_sourceErrorLevel: undefined  
baseTypes: ["MsPortalFx.Errors.AjaxError","MsPortalFx.Errors.Error"]  
code: undefined  
data: {"type":"GET","sessionId":"9e259d2b5dab4ad2972a1e6b76e844d2","status":401,"statusText":"Unauthorized","duration":28.5}  
errorLevel: 2  
errorThrown: Unauthorized  
extension: Microsoft_Azure_ContainerRegistries  
handled: undefined  
innerErrors: []  
jqXHR: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"errors\":[{\"code\":\"UNAUTHORIZED\",\"message\":\"authentication required\",\"detail\":[{\"Type\":\"registry\",\"Name\":\"catalog\",\"Action\":\"*\"}]}]}\n","responseJSON":{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"registry","Name":"catalog","Action":"*"}]}]},"status":401,"statusText":"Unauthorized"}  
message: ajaxExtended call failed  
name: Error  
source: undefined  
stack: null  
textStatus: error  
timestamp: 1567.8750000000002  
type: MsPortalFx.Errors.AjaxError
```

The error says I'm unauthorized, but I have the `Owner` role, so this should not be possible. Other users that are owner don't get this error.

Any clue how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error resolved itself after a couple of days.

I tried using a different browser and a different computer. Both methods still showed the error. So I think it might have been a bug.

Answer (score 0):

just uploaded my AKS and needed to pull lots of images from ACR. also got error afterwards due to load:

```json
{"type":"MsPortalFx.Errors.FetchDataError","baseTypes":["MsPortalFx.Errors.FetchDataError","MsPortalFx.Errors.DataError","MsPortalFx.Errors.Error"],"_errorData":{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error"},"extension":"Microsoft_Azure_ContainerRegistries","errorLevel":2,"timestamp":10180.93499999668,"source":"DataCache:2:3","message":"","name":"Error","innerErrors":[],"dataSetName":"DataCache:2:3"}
```